# Calling iterator from iterator, binding a parameter

Tags: ruby

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the following method:

```
def inner(p)
  %w(a b c d).each {|x| yield("#{p} inner #{x}")}
end
```

I would like a function `outer`, which is identical to `inner`, but where the parameter `p` is bound to a certain value, such as

```
def outer
  inner('haha') // This is NOT correct. It's just to give you an idea.
end
```

This does not work: If I do a

```
outer {|q| puts q}
```

I get a *LocalJumpError: yield called out of block*.

One workaround is obviously:

```
def outer
  inner('haha') { |x| yield(x) }
end
```

Not very elegant, because one *yield* just yields the next *yield*. A more concise way would be to pass the block around explicitly:

```
def inner(p, &block)
  %w(a b c d).each {|x| block.yield("#{p} inner #{x}")}
end

def outer(&block)
  inner('haha', &block)
end
```

While one might argue that writing the block argument explicitly is the better solution anyway, because we can see from the method signature already that a block is expected, I still wonder whether there is a clean way to achieve my goal without having a `&block` parameter.

*UPDATE*: Fix missing `&` in code.

Comment: I'd say the main use for block arguments is passing the block to other methods. IMO that's the cleanest approach. However, you have to write `inner('haha', &block)`, i.e. with `&`.

Comment: You are right. I had it correctly in my irb session, but picked the wrong line when pasting it into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine

```rb
def inner(p)
  %w(a b c d).each {|x| yield("#{p} inner #{x}")}
end

def outer(&block)
  inner('haha', &block)
end

def outer(&block)
  inner('haha', &block)
end

outer {|haha_and_item| puts haha_and_item}
# haha inner a
# haha inner b
# haha inner c
# haha inner d
```

`outer` seems to be just a wrapper method with the only purpose of storing the string `haha`. Then it accepts a block or a `Proc` that is going to be executed accordingly to the `inner` method definition.

If you want to use a method your examples are the only available syntax that I'm aware of. But it seems you are looking for a `closure` maybe a [carried one](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Proc.html#method-i-curry).

Here is an example:

```rb
def inner(parameter)
  inner_closure = -> (runable) do
     %w(a b c d).each { |x| runable.("#{parameter} inner #{x}") }
  end
  inner_closure.curry
end

parameter = 'ahah'
runable = proc {|haha_and_item| puts haha_and_item}
outer = inner(parameter)
outer[runable] 

outer = inner('closure')
outer[runable]
# ahah inner a
# ahah inner b
# ahah inner c
# ahah inner d
# closure inner a
# closure inner b
# closure inner c
# closure inner d
```